# If $(Av,Au)=(v,u)$ then matrix $A$ is orthogonal

Tags: matrices, inner-products, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $A\in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb R)$ and suppose that for every $u, v \in \Bbb R^{n}$ $$(Av,Au) = (v,u)$$ where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^{n}$. Prove $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

---

I wasn't able to solve it, I got to the point

$\left(Av,Au\right)=\left(Av\right)^{T}Au=v^{T}A^{T}Au$ and $\left(v,u\right)=v^{T}u$

$\left(Av,Au\right)=\left(v,u\right)\ \ \ ➜\ \ \ v^{T}A^{T}Au\ =\ v^{T}u$

and now I'm stuck.. I don't know if I can conclude that $A^{T}A=I_{R^{n}}$ just by the last equation, and if not how to get to the point I can show it..

Now I have two questions, first the official solution is this

> Let $u = e_{i}$ and $v = e_{j}$ . Then $(a_{i} , a_{j} ) = (Ae_{i} , Ae_{j} ) = (e_{i} , e_{j} ) = δ_{i,j}$ . Thus, the columns of $A$ are
> orthonormal, so $A$ is orthogonal.

This is super unclear.. what is $a_{i},a_{j}$? what is $δ_{i,j}$?
I understand that $(e_{i},e_{j})=0$ if $i \ne j$ and 1 otherwise, but why can we choose $v,u$ if it's a for every claim? If someone can explain to be the logic behind the solution I'd be grateful.

the second question is if there is another way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in answer to your second question. Here's another way to prove it, which avoids using $\ \delta_{i,j}\ $ and the $\ e_i\ $ (at least directly—they're really still there, lurking in the shadows).

You've deduced that
$$
v^TA^TAu=v^Tu
$$
for all $\ u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n\ $, which you can write as
$$
v^T\big(A^TA-I\big)u=0\ .
$$
If you put $\  v=\big(A^TA-I\big)u\ $ in this identity, then you get
$$
0=\big(\big(A^TA-I\big)u\big)^T\big(A^TA-I\big)u=\big\|\big(A^TA-I\big)u\big\|^2\ ,
$$
which implies that $\ \big(A^TA-I\big)u=0\ $.  This must hold for all $\ u\in\mathbb{R}^n\ $, which implies that $\ A^TA-I=0\ $, or, equivalently, $\ A^TA=I\ $, making $\ A\ $ orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

$e_i$ is an orthogonal basis. $a_i=Ae_i$ for each $i$. $\delta_{i,j}$ is called the kroneckerdelta function and is simply $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ if $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_{i,j}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta?wprov=sfti1). Defined by
$\delta_{i,j}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{i,j}=0$ otherwise as you noticed.

You can chose $u,v$ as you like as the identity

$$v^TA^TAu=v^Tu$$ is valid for any vectors $u,v$. In particular if you chose them among the vectors of the canonical basis $\{e_i\}$. $a_i$ seems just to be a notation for $A.e_i$.

The logic behind the solution, often used in linear algebra, is that if something is true for any vector, it is in particular true for the vectors of a basis. This is exactly what is done here for ordered pairs of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I can complete your solution. Fix $u$. From $v^TA^TAu = v^Tu$, we have
$$
v^T(A^TA - I)u = 0,
$$
or $(v, (A^TA - I)u) = 0$ for every vector $v$. It is easy to see that for a given vector $a$, if $(a,b) = 0$ for every $b$, then $a=0$ (compute $(a,e_j)$ for $j=1,\dots,n$). It follows that
$$
(A^TA-I)u = 0
$$ for every vector $u$ since $u$ is arbitrary. But this means that the rank of $A^TA-I$ is $0$, in order words, $A^TA - I = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_{i,j}$ is the kronecker delta which is equal to $0$ for $i\neq j$ and is $1$ when $i=j$. You can also say that $\delta _{i,j}$ is the (i,j)th element of the identity matrix $I$. $a_i $ is the vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ taking as elements the i-th column of $A$. That is: j-th component of the vector $a_i$  is $(a_i)_j= a_{ji}$ where $a_{ji}$ is the $(j,i)$-th element of the matrix A. We have $(Ae_i)_j =\sum_k a_{jk}(e_i)^k= a_{ji} =(a_i)_j$. So $Ae_i=a_i$

Now, from your equations and the definition of the inner product, we have $(a_i,a_j)= \sum_k a_{ki} a_{kj} = \delta_{i,j}$. Again,
$$( A^T A)_{ij} = \sum_k (A^T)_{ik}a_{kj} = \sum_k a_{ki} a_{kj} =\delta_{i,j}$$
Therefore, $A^TA=I$
Which proves what you needed.